# Works fine without ItemListener, but when I add it, it gives me a NullPointerException

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, calendar

I made a simple swing program for my class that changes time zone and some other stuff based on selected index in ComboBox. Works fine when the method run() looks like this:

```
public void run() {
        while(true){
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int h = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
            int m = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int s = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            l.setText(""+h+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
            try {
                t.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    }
```

But, when I try to redefine it and make the time change work, I get a null pointer exception in this line:

```
p.cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
```

Method run() looks like this, and it wont work. Any ideas?

```
public void run() {
    while(true){

        p.cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int h = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int m = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int s = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                int index = p.cb.getSelectedIndex();

                if(index == 0){
                    l.setText(""+h+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
                }
                else if(index == 1){
                    l.setText(""+(h-6)+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
                }
                else if(index == 2){
                    l.setText(""+(h-1)+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
                }
                else if(index == 3){
                    l.setText(""+(h-6)+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
                }
                else if(index == 4){
                    l.setText(""+(h+8)+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
                }
            }

        });

        try {
            t.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    }
}
```

In case anyone's confused, p is an instance of the JFrame class, while cb is a reference to ComboBox in the JFrame class.

Comment: where do you initialize `ComboBox`?

Comment: Post the stack trace, in case that BloodShura is not right. And btw: You are adding an ItemListener per second. That's not that good...

Comment: Thanks for the tip about ItemListener. I feel like an idiot, but I gotta ask, what exactly is a stack trace?

Comment: A stack trace is the list (actually: stack) of method calls that have been made until the point when your program crashed/halted. When you get the NullPointerException it's usually writing a lot more lines along with it. That's the call stack.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/W3tg35fq

That's the whole class where cb is located.

http://pastebin.com/KXwNdTKb - class where the threads are located.

Comment: If you look into your pasted `Nit` class, you will see that you nowhere initialize the variable `p`. Also, if you are using threads you must be aware that you can't update Swing components from a non-EDT thread. You should read up on this topic. Start for example here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 4):

A `NullPointerException` is being thrown because either `p` or `cb` have a `null` value.

Answer (score 1):

Your thread makes no sense now.  It is adding an ItemListener to the combobox every seconds, but each ItemListener is doing the same thing.  Also your thread is modifying a gui element off the EDT.  You need to be adding the ItemListener on the EDT.

I assume what you are trying to do is update a label every seconds or when the combo box is changed.

You should do this with no threads, but use a combination of a Swing Timer and the ItemListener.

```
// called on the EDT
void setup() {
     // create gui elements
     p.cb.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        updateTimeLabel();
     }
     new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           updateTimeLable()
        }
     });
 }

 private void updateTimeLabel() {
     Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     int h = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
     int m = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
     int s = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
     int index = p.cb.getSelectedIndex();

     if(index == 0){
        l.setText(""+h+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
     }
     else if(index == 1){
         l.setText(""+(h-6)+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
     }
     else if(index == 2){
         l.setText(""+(h-1)+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
     }
     else if(index == 3){
          l.setText(""+(h-6)+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
     }
     else if(index == 4){
          l.setText(""+(h+8)+":"+m+":"+(s<10?"0"+s:s));
     }
 }
```

As for why you are now getting null pointer exceptions, it could be caused by accessing a different variable that is not initialized yet, memory visibility problems, race condition of threads, or by modifying the GUI element off the EDT.  If you remove your thread all of these conditions besides the first go away.  It is then easy to make sure p.cb is initialized before calling the addItemListener method.

Also you should really use more descriptive names than p, cb, l.

Answer (score 0):

> In case anyone's confused, p is an instance of the JFrame class, while
>   cb is a reference to ComboBox in the JFrame class.

Instance of JFrame? Why are you following this method? Simply call `ComboBox` variable and add the listener! `p` seems to be `NULL`.